# PHP use array or extract to variables?

Tags: php

This is a question more of style than function. At the moment I use the following code to produce an array of values that have gone through various regex's in a function.

However this means having to reference the final array, which when adding lots of values to an SQL query can start to look quite messy compared to straight variables.

I could extract the array to variables after the function is called but am wondering if there is some way to do this from within the function and not run into problems with scope or should I actually avoid using straight variables and stick with the array?

```
<?php

function formData($form_vars)
{
    $regex_array = array(
        'alpha_num' => "/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]]/",
        'basic'     => "/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:],.\\'()&-]/"
    );

    foreach ($form_vars as $key => $var) {
        $regex = $regex_array[$var];
        $val = preg_replace($regex, '',  $_REQUEST[$key]);
        $vars[$key] = $val;
    }

    return $vars;
}

$vars = array(
    'address_one'   => "basic", 
    'address_two'   => "basic", 
    'address_three' => "basic", 
    'postal'        => "alpha_num"
);

$vars = formData($vars); 

echo $vars['address_one'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be point on your question and not diverge on other things I'd like to comment on:

`$regex_array` (which I'd call `$softTypeFilters`) and `$vars` (which I'd call `$fieldSoftTypes`) can be expternalized into a configuration file right now. So I'd stick with this and not use your other suggestion. You might loose this functionality (configurability) which is very powerful. And the code is still easy to read.

Comment: $vars will change each time a different form is used so can't go in a config file.

Comment: Give the form a name, too, and use that name (or the URL?) to fetch the soft types from that two-level array: `<form-name>.<field.name>`.

Comment: This site has so many forms that will create a very cumbersome file

Comment: Ok I desist :) But the more data you have, the more you need to structure it, and centralizing it this way **may** simplify later change management. But it also **may** complicate your code unneccessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract `$vars` and can use it to build your query easier (with a `function build_query($var)` for example, with an other loop)

**EDIT** detailled answer: I think about something like this:

```
<?php


function formData($vars, $alias)
{
  foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
  {
    // skip unknown fields
    if (!isset($vars[$k]))
      continue;
    // deal with input names != field name
    $field_name = isset($form_alias[$k])?$form_alias[$k]:$k;

    $vars[$key] = preg_replace($regex, '',  $_REQUEST[$key]);
    if (function_exists('preprocess_'.$key))
      $vars[$key] = call_user_func('preprocess_'.$key, $vars[$key]);
  }
  return $vars;
}

function buildQuery($vars)
{
  $sql = '';
  // use a query builder, PDO prepared statements or anything 
  foreach($vars as $field => $value)
  {
    // ...
  }
  return $sql;
}

$vars = array(
  'address_one'   => "basic", 
  'address_two'   => "basic", 
  'address_three' => "basic", 
  'postal'        => "alpha_num",
);
$form_alias = array(
  'address1'   => "address_one", 
  'address2'   => "address_two", 
  'address3'   => "address_three",
);

$vars = formData($vars, $form_alias);

$query = buildQuery($vars);
```

Comment: That's only true if the db field names all correlate to the array keys, also I need to do some preprocessing where again straight variables would be easier to read.

Comment: A better solution would be to use php class, object models, and methods to validate and format datas